# Oracle Query on Max(Date)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

My goal is to create a query and then an update statement that will update the CI field to '1' but only if the max(vt_end) is less than sysdate **AND** only if there is not already a record updated for the max(vt_end) of 31-dec-9999 for that particular code.  I have my basic query below but I'm not sure how to identify just those records to update.

```
SELECT CODE,
     MAX (VT_END),
     TT_STOP,
     MOST_RECENT_IND AS MRI,
     CURRENT_IND AS CI
FROM TABLE
WHERE TT_STOP > SYSDATE AND CODE IN ('0001F', '0001M', '0001T')
GROUP BY CODE,
     VT_END,
     MOST_RECENT_IND,
     CURRENT_IND
ORDER BY CODE, VT_END


CODE    VT_END       TT_STOP    MRI CI  
0001F   12/31/2004  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   12/31/2006  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   3/31/2007   12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   12/31/2007  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   12/31/2011  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   12/31/2012  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001F   12/31/9999  12/31/9999  1   1  
0001T   12/31/2003  12/31/9999  0   0  
0001T   12/31/2004  12/31/9999  0   0
```

I also have tried this query but it is wrong because it brings back the record for 0001F 12/31/2012 which is incorrect because there is a record already for it for '31-dec-9999'

```
SELECT CODE,
     MAX (VT_END),
     MOST_RECENT_IND AS MRI,
     CURRENT_IND AS CI
FROM SRC_PROCDR_DESCRIPTOR_SCD2
WHERE TT_STOP > SYSDATE AND CODE IN ('0001F', '0001M', '0001T')
AND VT_END <> '31-dec-9999'
GROUP BY CODE,
     MOST_RECENT_IND,
     CURRENT_IND
ORDER BY CODE

Incorrect Results:
CODE    VT_END       TT_STOP    MRI CI 
0001F   12/31/2012  0   0
0001T   12/31/2004  0   0
```

Results should be

```
CODE    VT_END       TT_STOP    MRI CI 
0001T   12/31/2004  12/31/9999  0   0   - Update to '1' on CI  
--This should be the only record returned in the above query to put into an 
UPDATE statement.
```

Comment: If your goal is to create an update statement, why are you using `SELECT`?

Comment: Remove VT_END from the GROUP_BY.

Comment: I'm trying to identify the records first and then create an update statement.

Comment: I removed the VT_END from the group by but I still get 2 records for 0001F.  Ultimately, I just need 1 record returned which is 0001T VT_END 12/31/2004.

Comment: I edited my title and results.  Thanks you for the feedback.

Comment: Why would `0001F  12/31/2012  12/31/9999  0  0` not be returned? It seems to satisfy all the other rules.

Comment: There is a also a record for    0001F   12/31/9999  12/31/9999  1   1  and that is the current record, so I do not need to bring back     0001F 12/31/2012 12/31/9999 0 0 in my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `MAX()` but you need to use `EXISTS`, because using `MAX()` your can mix values from different rows, and I suppose that you need to update using both `CODE` and `VT_END`:

```
SELECT CODE, VT_END
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TT_STOP > SYSDATE
  AND CODE IN ('0001F', '0001M', '0001T')
  AND VT_END <> '31-dec-9999'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
    WHERE T1.CODE=TABLE1.CODE -- join condition
      AND T1.VT_END>TABLE1.VT_END) -- filter condition
ORDER BY CODE
```

This would return the rows with the maximum `VT_END` for each `CODE` only if the maximum `VT_END` is not `'31-dec-9999'` (with `NOT EXIST (...)` you get the maximum date and with `VT_END <> '31-dec-9999'` you filter out the rows already updated).

Comment: Great Solution!  Thank you for explaining the logic.  I truly appreciate the help and guidance.

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for making an effort to learn and not just copy'n'paste the solution.